# Adding element to default arraylist

Tags: java

I have been unable to add new elements in default array list .. somebody help me. i have searched about it for last 2 days but i couldn't understand the logic behind it

```
public class User {

private int id;
private String name;

public User(int id, String name) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
}
```

}

```
public class User2 {

public static List<User> list = new ArrayList<>();

public User2(int i, String abc){
    list.add(new User(1,"abc"));
    list.add(new User(2,"bcd"));
}

public List<User> getList() {
    return list;
}

public void setList(List<User> list) {
    this.list = list;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    User2 user2 = new User2(3,"def");
    List<User2> usr = new ArrayList<>();
    usr.add(user2);

    list.add((User) usr);

    for(User temp: list){
        System.out.println(" listing "+temp);
    }

}
```

}

Comment: `unable to add new elements` - please explain.

Comment: Which one is the "default array list"?

Comment: `list.add((User) usr)` is casting `usr` to a `User`. `usr` is a `List<User2>`. Can you please explain why you are doing that and what you think it does?

Comment: A `List<User2>` is not a `User` (and you cannot cast it to one). Exactly, what are you trying to do here?

Comment: Actually i have two default values in list of type User which are 1;abc and 2 ;bcd and from anywhere i want to add 3;cde to that list .. i am unable

Comment: `User2` is not `User`.... should it be a subclass of `User`?  `list.add(new User(3, "def"));`

Comment: If all you want to do is Add new user to list then you can do this list.add(new User(3, "def"))...Also note that when you are doing  User2 user2 = new User2(3,"def"); you are not actually adding them. Because in the constructor "abc" and "bcd" are being inserted into the list

Answer (score 1):

`list.add((User) usr);` will provoke a `ClassCastException` as `usr` that is not very well named is a `List`. And a `User` cannot be cast to a `List` type.

What you need is adding the array list elements in another one :

```
  list.addAll(usr);
```

A more readable code would be :

```
User2 user2 = new User2(3,"def");
List<User2> listToAdd = new ArrayList<>();
listToAdd.add(user2);
// add the local list elements to the static field list
list.addAll(listToAdd);
```

Answer (score 1):

In this line:

```
list.add((User) usr);
```

You try to cast a `List<User2>` into a `User`. It won't work. I think that what the error must tell you.

But I might be able to see what you want to do. In Java you can't pass an `User2` which doesn't have any link with `User` to a `List<User>`. You need to define a common interface and make both classes implement it. Or make the class `User2` extend the class `User`.

Comment: See @davidxxx 's post. Furthermore I think you need to add `extends User` after `public class User2`. This means `User2` IS a `User`, and that a `User2` can be used anywhere a `User` is expected.